# Accessing Variables of Layers in Keras

Tags: keras

If I were to follow the guide and integrate with my TensorFlow workflow (https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html) as with others, you cannot access the weight variable because we **won't be building the model** as shown in the guide. We're merely using the layers. There is no need to compile when we use it as a simplified interface to TensorFlow. **How then do we access the weights (variables)?**

Because if we use with TensorFlow like the guide, we **do not call** `Model` or `Compile` but merely use the layers to build.

Comment: Can you add the code where you would like to get the variables?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the part where the model is defined as:

```
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(img)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
preds = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)  # output layer with 10 units and a softmax activation
```

Then you are right, you cannot access the variables, but it is because we don't give the layer a name (we are only tracking the tensor `x`).

If you want to access the variables, while using a similar notation you would have to do something like this:

```
l1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')
l2 = Dense(128, activation='relu')
out = Dense(10, activation='softmax')
preds = out(l2(l1(img)))
```

Then you can access the variables of, say `l1` by `l1.weights`.

---

If you are interested in how to access the variables when using `Sequential` use: `model.layers[i].weights` where `i` is the index of the layer you are interested in.